# HG: clone does not have any changesets

Tags: mercurial, clone

I have a hg respository located in a `~/Server` folder on my computer. when I run `hg summary` from the root of that project, I get the following:

```
parent: 98:408483c17026 tip
 final proposal page set up
branch: GS_Clients
commit: 6 deleted (clean)
update: (current)
```

So I wanted to make a backup copy of this project in my dropbox folder, so I ran :

```
hg clone <current_source> ~/Dropbox/Repositories/<new_source>
```

yet when I run `hg summary` in the new directory, is states that it is at revision 0:

```
parent: 0:b03c2c025c61 
 inital commit
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
```

I've tried all manners of pushing,pulling and updating, but I can't get the new repo up to date.

How can I make a clone that is up to date, and/or how can I get this repo up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first summary is on branch `GS_Clients`, while the second one, because it is a fresh clone, is on the `default` branch. Try `hg update GS_Clients`.

The `update: (current)` line only means you're at a head of the current branch.

*I figure only rev 0 is on the `default` branch, and all your other commits are on `GS_Clients` or other named branches. Commands like `log`, `glog`, and UIs like TortoiseHg would have made that pretty obvious, where `summary` does not.*